# Dynamically show values from one state to another in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have four components named as UserHome, SearchFlight, Events and Alerts

I got UserHome component where I am importing all components

```
<SearchFlight/>
<Events />
<Alerts />
```

In **SearchFlight** I have a form with two inputs and a button. When I am clicking the button I am calling a function which will calculate some JSON values(*events*, *alerts arrays*) for the corresponding inputs I provided then I want to Inject these inputs **dynamically** in Events and Alerts component.

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            open: false,
            airport: '',
            search_flight_no: '',
        };

      }

handleSubmit= event =>{
        event.preventDefault();

        var airportValueSelected= this.state.airport;
        var flightValue= this.state.search_flight_no;
        var airportList= FlightInfo.Airport;
        for(var rootKey in airportList){
          if(rootKey===airportValueSelected)
           {

               airportList[rootKey].forEach(element => {


                   if(element.flight_no===flightValue){

                    for(var m=0;m<element.Events.length;m++){

                     var singleEvent={
                       event_name:'',
                       date_time:'',
                     };

                      singleEvent.event_name=element.Events[m].event_name;
                      singleEvent.date_time=element.Events[m].date_time;
                      this.state.events.push(singleEvent);
                    }

                    for(var s=0;s<element.Alerts.length;s++){

                      this.state.alerts.push(element.Alerts[s]["Alert"+(s+1)]);

                    }

                   }
                   // Here I am getting both events and alerts arrays
               });
               if(this.state.events.length<1 && this.state.alerts.length<1){
                this.setState({ open: true });
               }
               else{

               }


           }
        }
```

This code will get that events and alerts array so I have commented where I am getting it.

Rest here is my UserHome

```
 constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            events:[],
            alerts:[],
        };

      }

      setEvents = newEvents => this.setState({events: newEvents})


    render(){
        const {events} = this.state
        return(
            <div >
                <div style={{display:'inline-block',minHeight:'470px',}}>  
                <div className="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
                <div className="container">
                    <SearchFlight events={events} setEvents={this.setEvents} />
                </div>
                <div className="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
                <button className="btn btn-primary" style={{position:'absolute',right:'0',top:'62px',}}>
                <Link to={{pathname: "/"}}>LOGOUT</Link></button>

                </div>




            </div>
        );
    }
```

**Error:** cannot read property of push undefined

Answer (score 1):

Using the react philosophy, you should have `UserHome` have the global state and pass it to its children (the 3 other components). Also, UserHome should pass a function to `SearchFlight` when SearchFlight has the return of the submit.

This function will then update the state of UserHome, and allow its children to have the updated data.

Example:

```
class UserHome extends Component {
  state = {
    events: []
  }

  addEvent = newEvent => this.setState(state => {
    const {events} = this.state
    return [...events, newEvent]
  })

  render() {
    const {events} = this.state
    return (
      <>
        <SearchFlight events={events} addEvent={this.addEvent} />
        <Events events={events} />
        <Alerts events={events} />
      </>
    )
  }
}


class SearchFlight extends Component {
  handleSubmit = () => {
    const {addEvent} = this.props

    // create a new event here
    // const myNewEvent = {...}

    addEvent(myNewEvent)
  }
  render() {
    const {events} = this.props
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleSubmit} />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I have declared and initialize the state for events and alerts in UserHome but how do I pass it to another component and secondly the function I am calling that function on click of a button and that button is not in UserHome

Comment: In react, you pass everything through props (data or functions). I've edited the answer to show you an example

Comment: setEvents to set events in UserHome state similarly setAlerts I need to have in SearchFlight. What is confusing is why did you have const events in SearchFlight and how you declare it in curly braces and lastly in SearchFlight what is this.props means I want to set the values which I have retrieved from JSON

Comment: I think you may find more complete answers directly in the React documentation especially on theses two links: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html and https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html .
The first will explain how to pass data from a component to its children. And the second explain how to pass data from a children component to its parent.

Comment: ok but if I used your code in SearchFlight it says newEvents is not defined

Comment: Yes, instead of newEvents, you must use whatever variable which holds your dynamically created events

Comment: I have updated my code and there is new problem it says cannot read property push of undefined at this line `this.state.events.push(singleEvent);`
`

Comment: First, make sure you only call `this.state` from inside UserHome. Then, in React, this.state is read-only. Which means you can't edit or push into an array. If you want to push a new element in the array, you can do the following:
`this.setState(prevState => ({events: [...events,singleEvent]}) `. You can read more about this here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: yeah I get it since events is not inside UserHome. So, first thing is below code is giving syntactical error when I used it instead of push also one more thing as you said I have to use this.state inside UserHome since events state is defined but how do I use it then in SearchFlight I tried `this.props.event.push` but didn't work

Comment: You use `this.setState` inside the `setEvents` function of UserHome. Then, you pass `setEvents` to SearchFlights as a props. Finally, you call `setEvents` from SearchFlights like so: `this.props.setEvents(myNewEvent)`

Comment: can you make changes in your code to show exactly what to do maybe I might be missing something it's not working....because still I need to push those array values somewhere then only I could set

Comment: I just edited to show you how to do it. Note: `[...events, newEvent]` creates a copy of `events` with `newEvent` at the end

Comment: I got the state in SearchFlight component updated the state with events and alerts values. Now when I do `console.log(newEvents)` in UserHome I get nothing probably because I might need componentdidReceiveprops() method which will update the state. Please tell me if I am wrong